# How can I set view shadow only on sides for view with elevation

Tags: android

I have a `RecyclerView` with various view types. Each view has own background with top, bottom or no rounded corners. Each use the same view elevation.
This is one of the backgrounds in XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="@color/card_background_pressed"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <size
                android:width="1dp"
                android:height="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/card_background_normal" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

When views are laid out next to each other without any margin it looks like having the same background. This is my way for creating dynamic card background. In other words I can create single looking card from multiple items in `RecyclerView`

**Problem**

As you can see below, when 2 views are laid out next to each other their shadows are overlapping each other in the corners, even when corner background radius is 0.

So does anyone know how to fix it? I care only for API 21+ so need to worry about older versions support. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: what is your expected result? is it no overlapping but still connected shadow?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin exactly, I need connected shadow so it looks like a single card

Comment: Then set the shadow to the recycleview instead, not on each view.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I can't, all items in RecyclerView create more cards, depends on data. Also if I do it, RecyclerView's card would remain in position when user scroll and it gives bad look&feel.

Comment: A card should be one recycler item, that way there's no problem with shadows. Change your adapter so you have one item - one card pattern.

Comment: @headsvk This is one to one relation but some cards use only top or bottom or no rounded corners to make a group of items look like one card. Problem is that shadows of those items somehow create this thing marked with red circle on my screenshot.

Comment: There's nothing about stacking cards close to each other in the material specs, I would guess this is the intended behavior. You broke it down to too many pieces. Why can't you just put the 2 text views and the image into one recycler view item?

Comment: @headsvk I wish I could but it's far more complex UI and it's up to API to build UI so I would have to predicts all kind of combinations, also for some lists card start with first item and ends until first header is found which could be far away in the list.

Comment: Have you tried setting a shadow with drawables? That way you could use top-right-bottom-left shadow for the first card item and only right-bottom-left shadow for subsequent items. This should remove the overlap.

Comment: Y dont you put the entire recycleview inside a cardView , so that you can avoid these problems.

Comment: you simply can use either cardview using support lib, or can simply give 
android:elevation="10dp"
it's that simple.

Comment: I understand that there are more cards in the RecyclerView and more items can be inside a card. So it's not simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have not tried with `RippleDrawable` but I think the idea is the same. So let's start with a simple case:

Android provides a class called [ViewOutlineProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewOutlineProvider.html). You can use this class to create your own shadow. For your problem you can set offset for your bottom view's shadow so the overlapping area is drawn by the shadow of top view.

Some code please:

First I am trying to create your problem with this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/top"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:elevation="25dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Top" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bottom"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/top"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                android:elevation="25dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Bottom" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

it is a little hard to recognize overlapping shadows:

[image]

Now I add some arbitrary y offset by this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView mTopTv,mBottomTv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mTopTv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.top);
        mBottomTv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bottom);
        mBottomTv.setOutlineProvider(new ViewOutlineProvider() {
            @Override
            public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
                outline.setRect(0, 50, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and the result is:

[image]

As comparing two images it is clear that the overlapping area is eliminated.

Comment: That looks promising, how did you calculate that Y offset to be 50?

Comment: I set it arbitrary to show the demo, but you can use the elevation value and a function that converts dp to px, so you can set exact value.

Comment: I had to take off quite a bit of the top outline to make the shadow fit in my case, and to avoid the view being clipped, one could set `cardView.setClipToOutline(false);`